# How to aggregate events in flink stream before merging with current state by reduce function?

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

My events are like: `case class Event(user: User, stats: Map[StatType, Int])`

Every event contains +1 or -1 values in it.
I have my current pipeline that works fine but produces new event for every change of statistics.

```scala
eventsStream
    .keyBy(extractKey)
    .reduce(reduceFunc)
    .map(prepareRequest)
    .addSink(sink)
```

I'd like to aggregate these increments in a time window before merging them with the current state. So I want the same rolling reduce but with a time window.

Current simple rolling reduce:

```
500 – last reduced value
+1
-1
+1

Emitted events: 501, 500, 501
```

Rolling reduce with a window:

```
500 – last reduced value
v-- window
+1
-1
+1
^-- window

Emitted events: 501
```

I've tried naive solution to put time window just before `reduce` but after reading the docs I see that reduce now has different behavior.

```scala
eventsStream
    .keyBy(extractKey)
    .timeWindow(Time.minutes(2))
    .reduce(reduceFunc)
    .map(prepareRequest)
    .addSink(sink)
```

It seems that I should make keyed stream and reduce it after reducing my time window:

```scala
eventsStream
    .keyBy(extractKey)
    .timeWindow(Time.minutes(2))
    .reduce(reduceFunc)
    .keyBy(extractKey)
    .reduce(reduceFunc)
    .map(prepareRequest)
    .addSink(sink)
```

Is it the right pipeline to solve a problem?

Comment: Actually, are you having any issue or error message when putting the windowing before the `reduce`? AFAIK that should work.

Comment: In the stream I have events like `case class Event(user: User, stats: Map[StatType, Int])`. Every event contains +1 or -1 values in it. As I've read in the docs `reduce` on keyed stream emits a new state. So if I have a value of 500 for some user and stat type it will emit 501 if there's +1 event in the stream. But reduce that is applied to windowed stream reduces only those events that are inside a window. So it seems like it will emit increments instead of a new state.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably different options, but one would be to implement a `WindowFunction` and then run `apply` after the windowing:

```
eventsStream
    .keyBy(extractKey)
    .timeWindow(Time.minutes(2))
    .apply(new MyWindowFunction)
```

(`WindowFuntion` takes type parameters for the type of the input value, the type of the output value and the type of the key.)

There's an example of that [in here](https://github.com/streaming-with-flink/examples-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/io/github/streamingwithflink/chapter1/AverageSensorReadings.scala#L57). Let me copy the relevant snippet:

```
/** User-defined WindowFunction to compute the average temperature of SensorReadings */
class TemperatureAverager extends WindowFunction[SensorReading, SensorReading, String, TimeWindow] {

  /** apply() is invoked once for each window */
  override def apply(
    sensorId: String,
    window: TimeWindow,
    vals: Iterable[SensorReading],
    out: Collector[SensorReading]): Unit = {

    // compute the average temperature
    val (cnt, sum) = vals.foldLeft((0, 0.0))((c, r) => (c._1 + 1, c._2 + r.temperature))
    val avgTemp = sum / cnt

    // emit a SensorReading with the average temperature
    out.collect(SensorReading(sensorId, window.getEnd, avgTemp))
}
```

I don't know how your data looks so I can't attempt a full answer, but that should serve as inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your proposed pipeline will have the desired effect. The window will reduce together the 2-minute batches. The results of those batches will flow into the final reduce, which will produce an updated result after each of its inputs (which are the window results).